# QML ListView delegate with Component Row does't render correctly

Tags: qml, qt5

And now I have a problem with my qml script. here's the simple code:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    
    Rectangle {
        id: root
        
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "green"
        
        SystemPalette { id: activePalette }
        
        ColumnLayout {
            id: rightPanel
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.rightMargin: 10
            
            anchors.fill: parent
            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log(this, width, parent, parent.width)
            }
            
            ListView {
                spacing: 2
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                model: ListModel {
                    ListElement {
                        name: "nihao"
                        value: "1"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        name: "fds"
                        value: "2"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        name: "fdssd"
                        value: "4"
                    }
                }
                delegate: Component {
                    // Rectangle {
                    //     color: "yellow"
                    //     height: 40
                    //     width: parent.width
                    Row {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        spacing: 2
                        height: 40
                        width: 200 
                        Rectangle {
                            color: activePalette.window
                            height: 25
                            width: 100
                            border.color: "white"
                            border.width: 3
                            Text {
                                anchors.centerIn: parent
                                text: name
                            }
                        }
                        Rectangle {
                            color: activePalette.window
                            height: 25
                            width: 100
                            border.color: "white"
                            border.width: 3
                            Text {
                                anchors.centerIn: parent
                                text: value
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code does't display correctly when I use qmlscene to render it, it even render nothing if the ListModel is too long.
But, if I uncomment out the "Rectangle" code in delegate component, it works well. So I'm comfused with the difference between Reactangle and Row for that they are all inherited from Item. And what should be placed into the delegate component as its direct child?

Comment: Remove `Component` as unnecessary element. it will be enough:  `delegate: Row {`. Also remove `anchors.fill: parent` and it will work as expected. You shouldn't use anchoring and setting static size together. Also don't use  `anchors.fill: parent` for a delegate. In this case `parent` is the `ListView` so what do you expect to get?

Comment: Thanks for reply, It is indeed the anchors.fill that make something wrong. Running this code with the newest qt(qt.5.15), I get the more error message like: 
`QML ListView: possible QQuickItem::polish() loop`. And, after removing anchors.fill, everything is ok now